# How do I allow a facebook page admin to select only the specific pages they want my app to manage(manage_pages)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I'm building a facebook app using Ruby on Rails and the Koala gem to build my own login flow.

https://github.com/arsduo/koala
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/

**My question is pretty simply.**

*Assuming the following case:*

-A user who is trying to connect to my app has multiple facebook pages that they admin. I would like them to be able to select only the specific pages that they want me to admin while denying access to the rest.

The reason is that alot of the admins that will be using my app manages large numbers of pages. I cant imagine them being ok with me getting permissions to all their pages when i only need permissions for a small subset of pages.

I'm using Ruby on Rails

Comment: This is the most polite question I have come across on SO.

Comment: It is not possible. The permissions will only give you all or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. According to Facebook "[Tokens and Rules](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens)", the "manage_pages" permission is:

> Enables your app to retrieve Page Access Tokens for the Pages and Apps that the person administrates.

You could get tokens just for the pages they wish to manage with you and add it to your TOC